# Does it make sense to give reverse iterators to std::any_of and the like?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to check if a value exists in a vector. It is **most likely at the end of the vector**, does it make sense to use reverse iterators like this:

```
std::vector<int> v{};
//... add a lot of values ...
const int valueToCheckFor{42};
if (std::any_of(v.crbegin(), v.crend(), [valueToCheckFor](const auto x){ return valueToCheckFor == x; }
```

or is

```
if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [valueToCheckFor](const auto x){ return valueToCheckFor == x; }
```

just the same, since the order of execution in `std::any_of` is not specified and I'd be better off by using a for-loop?

this is for c++11/c++14

Comment: `std::find(v.crbegin(), v.crend(), 42)) != v.crend()`. This is guarantees to search in order.

Comment: Keep in mind that **algorithms** operate on **ranges**. They don't care where you get the range from. `std::vector` is one way of managing ranges, but it is not the only way. Again: the algorithm doesn't know or care.

Answer (score 2):

If the element is likely at end.

```
std::any_of(v.crbegin(), 
           v.crend(), 
           [valueToCheckFor](const auto x)
           { return valueToCheckFor == x; 
          });
```

make more sense and would work correctly.